# How do I make it so only one element is shown at once?

Tags: javascript, dom, jquery-selectors, event-listener

When the box is clicked on the insides for each of the boxes are shown, I only want one to show up at a time.

```js
function select() {
  const outside = document.querySelectorAll('.box')
  const insides = document.querySelectorAll('.insides')
  insides.forEach(insides => {
    outside.forEach(box => {
      box.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {
        box.setAttribute("id", "selected")
        box.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
          box.classList.add('hover')
          if (document.getElementById('selected')) {
            insides.classList.add('insidesHover')
          }
        })
      })
      box.addEventListener('mouseleave', (e) => {
        box.classList.remove('hover')
        box.setAttribute('id', 'testBox')
        insides.classList.remove('insidesHover')
      })
    })
  })
}

function newOption() {
  var optionRow = document.createElement("div");
  optionRow.setAttribute("class", "answers");
  optionRow.setAttribute("id", "optionRow");

  var option = document.createElement("input");
  option.setAttribute("type", "radio");
  option.setAttribute("name", "options");
  option.setAttribute("id", "options");

  var optionBox = document.createElement("div");
  optionBox.setAttribute("class", "answerContainer")
  optionBox.setAttribute("id", "optionBox")

  var text = document.createElement("input");
  text.setAttribute("type", "text");
  text.setAttribute("name", "option");
  text.setAttribute("id", "option");
  text.setAttribute("placeholder", "Enter Option");

  optionBox.append(optionRow);
  optionRow.append(option);
  optionRow.append(text);

  document.getElementById("selected").append(optionRow);
  array()
}
```

```css
.testContainer {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  padding: 1%;
  background-color: #333;
  height: auto;
  color: white;
}

.box {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 25px;
  border: 5px blue solid;
}

.hover {
  border: #780119 5px solid;
}

.insides {
  display: none;
}

.insidesHover {
  display: flex;
}

.buttons {
  display: none;
}

.buttonsHover {
  display: flex;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="testContainer">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="insides" id="testBox">
      <input type="text" class="insidesHover">
      <button onclick="newOption()" class="buttonsHover"> </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="testContainer">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="insides" id="testBox">
      <input type="text" class="insidesHover">
      <button onclick="newOption()" class="buttonsHover"> </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="testContainer">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="insides" id="testBox">
      <input type="text" class="insidesHover">
      <button onclick="newOption()" class="buttonsHover"> </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So the problem I am having is that I want to use a querySelectorAll() for the class of .box, which on click changes the outline to show it is being selected. Which is something that is fully functional and works. However, I also want it to show the inside pieces on click as well but only for one box at a time, which on the event listener of leave will disappear again. Once the inside of adding new options goes away, I need the options that were put in to stay. I have tried putting everything in one div class where the opacity is set to 0, but it makes it so the new options don't stay visible. I have also tried rearranging the variables so that the insides are affected first, which had no effect on the actual functionality. I believe the true issue lies in the fact that when the id, selected, is active it triggers all boxes to be active instead of individual ones. I am not entirely sure how to go about rectifying this issue and would like some advice on moving forward. If you have any questions or if something needs clarification please let me know! Thank you for your time and wish you all a good day!